# `Calculate total row count` (icon of two green circled arrows) in DBeaver throws "Error executing error count", but manual choice of >200 rows works

Tags: bug, dbeaver

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') FROM MY_TABLE1 ...' at line 1

And in the details:

```
  Error executing row count
  SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') FROM temp.MY_TABLE' at line 1
  SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') FROM temp.MY_TABLE' at line 1
  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') FROM temp.MY_TABLE' at line 1
  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') FROM temp.MY_TABLE' at line 1
```

[image]

when clicking on `Calculate total row count` green double arrow (circle)

[image]

If I enter 999999 rows instead of the 200, I can also fetch all rows and see the full number of rows in the task bar as always.

[image]

This error popped up during the day, it still worked at one time, and some minute later, it did not work anymore and also did not work anymore on two other computers, therefore it seems reproducible, happened at first on 27-02-2022.

> DBeaver Universal Database Manager
> Version 21.3.5.202202200327

Comment: The bug seems to have disappeared, works again. Leaving this because of the workaround.

Comment: :) Now it is there again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update 2022-03-14:

The right version 22.0.0 got automatically installed when opening DBeaver.

[image]

[image]

#### Update 2022-03-07

Update out now on 07.03.2022 and:

> Data editor - Row count calculation query was fixed

[image]

Mind that the new version 22.0.0 is not yet available for snap installer / snap refresh, and probably many more installer at https://dbeaver.io/download/. But you can find downloads for all OS in the git repo at https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/releases.

It was said before that the fix will be available in DBeaver version 22.0.0 and that the release was planned for March 3 2022.

See the closed git issue [Error thrown by "Calculate total row count" following MySQL SELECT query #15600](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/15600).

Answer (score 2):

me too, it is bug of ver 21.3.5
not work 'calculate total row count'

install ver 21.3.4
https://dbeaver.io/files/21.3.4/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Right, tested, works both for the snap and the non-snap installation.